# Android Button Blinkin Animation with different images

Tags: java, android, animation, button

I'm developing an android application and i need to do an button animation.

I'm a two different image to button and i want setBackground of button with this 2 images alternate them with 500ms delay and in total only 2 seconds.

How i can do this and make program wait to end of animation when i run them?

my button have an background and an text. I want this Order SeQuence: Click Button -> Alert Dialog -> If Yes, Exit Dialog - > Call Animation(And all Activity wait for this animation) -> In the end of Animation call another function and continues the program

Regards

Answer (score 1):

put below xml in drawable with name 'frame' (for example and frame0 and frame1 is two different umages)

```
<animation-list android:id="@+id/my_animation"
    android:oneshot="true" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame0" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame0" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

put below code into your layout xml

```
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Use below code into oncreate() method

```
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =    (AnimationDrawable)img.getDrawable();
        frameAnimation.setCallback(img);
        frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
        frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Hello,

This isn't what i looking for because my button have an background and an text.

I want this Order SeQuence:

Click Button -> Alert Dialog -> If Yes, Exit Dialog - > Call Animation(And all Activity wait for this animation) -> In the end of Animation call another function and continues the program.

Regards if anyone can helpme

Comment: Okay..You need to mention all these things in your question.

Comment: I know, im Sorry and Thank you